# How to remove the first instance of an element in a tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

So for example, I have a tuple:

```
(7, 5, 3, 3, 6, 3, 9)
```

and I would want to take out only the first number 3 in that tuple so that it would look like this instead:

```
(7, 5, 3, 6, 3, 9)
```

The code I've written uses the filter tool to take out the 3, however it takes out all the other 3's as well:

```
def takeOut(k, r):
    newK = tuple(filter(lambda x: x != r, k))
    return newK

print(takeOut((7, 5, 3, 3, 6, 3, 9), 3))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with slicing:

```
def remove_element(seq, element):
    try:
        index = seq.index(element)
        return seq[:index] + seq[index + 1:]
    except ValueError:  # element doesn't exist
        return seq
```

Answer (score 6):

The reason this isn't as straightforward as one might think is that tuples are immutable.

An easy way would be to convert to `list`, use `remove` to remove the first instance, and convert back to tuple:

```
t = (7, 5, 3, 3, 6, 3, 9)

t2 = list(t)
t2.remove(3)
tuple(t2)
# (7, 5, 3, 6, 3, 9)
```

As a Function:

```
def takeOut(k, r):
    k2 = list(k)
    k2.remove(r)
    return tuple(k2)

takeOut((7, 5, 3, 3, 6, 3, 9), 3)
# (7, 5, 3, 6, 3, 9)
```

Comment: I had the exact same solution. I'm checking if there are any faster one

Comment: A general solution would be nice to have which removes all similar pairs to just first occurrence...

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the fact that `index` only returns the first index of an element, and cast the generator expression back to a tuple:

```
>>> tuple(e for i, e in enumerate(k) if i != k.index(3))
(7, 5, 3, 6, 3, 9)
```

Answer (score 2):

The fastest and often the simplest way to do things in Python is to use any built-in methods it has whenever possible. In this case that would be tuple (sequence) methods (see [Common Sequence Operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) in the documentation for details):

```
def remove_first_inst(seq, elem):
    try:
        i = seq.index(elem)
    except ValueError:
        return seq  # elem was not in sequence.
    return seq[:i] + seq[i+1:]


t = (7, 5, 3, 3, 6, 3, 9)

print(remove_first_inst(t, 3))  # -> (7, 5, 3, 6, 3, 9)
```

Doing it that way in this case means the function would also work with `list`s, since they're also sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Tuples are immutable, which wouldn't really be "removing an object" from the tuple.

When you remove it, you'll be creating a new tuple.
There's probably *hundreds* of ways to solve this.

```
def takeOut(k, r):
    first = True
    newK = []
    for item in k:
       if first and item == r:
           first = False
           continue
       newK.append(item)
    return tuple(newK)

print(takeOut((7, 5, 3, 3, 6, 3, 9), 3))
```